# Elastic search version 2.3 to 5.1

Tags: elasticsearch

My projects java version runs on 1.7.0_71. and my elastic search version is 1.4.3 . Now we want to upgrade the es to 2.3.5. Is it ok to simply upgrade the elastic search version from 1.4.3 to 2.3.5. or should i upgrade the java to 1.8 then migrate it to 5.1 .. because my ultimate target is to for elastic search 5.1 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be ok to upgrade from 1.4 to 2.3, but it will be trickier (impossible) to go straight from 1.4 to 5.1 or 1.4->2.3->5.x **without reindexing**.

Segments created two Lucene major versions back are not supported.
So, even if you updgrade to 2.3, there still might be old segments (created in 1.4) when you upgrade to 5.x. There is an upgrade indices API, but as [the documentation says](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-upgrade.html) it will not be useful for a 1.x -> 5.x upgrade.

Regarding the Java version, yes, you need Java 1.8, at least update 73: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/setup.html#jvm-version